# ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople wrong on device - right on simulator

Tags: ios

I have the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
CFErrorRef *error = nil;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
if (error)
}
NSArray *arrayOfPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

It works on the simulator and gives me the expected results - however on the device the number of contacts is 0 and there is no error (the app strangely does not ask me for permissions to access the address book - I even deleted  and reinstalled the app)
Any Ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

On ios 6 you need get access to the Address Book.
Call `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion()` to get the permission.
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12517542/1375233) and [AddressHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12533918/1375233)

```c
CFErrorRef error = nil;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error %@", error);
    }else if (granted){
        // Do what you want with the Address Book

    }else{
        NSLog(@"permission denied");
    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
});
```