# Not able to retrieve phone contacts in iphone, but working fine for simulator

Tags: ios

I want to get contact details in an iPhone with information like First Name, Last Name, Phone Number, Phone Number Type, Email Address, Email Address Type etc..

I am able to do this for simulator but not for iphone

Can anyone please tell what am i missing??

```
CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
NSLog(@"COUNT : %ld", ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook));

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {

    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );

    NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
    NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
    NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);

    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);    
}
```

Comment: Paste the code which is working for simulator.

Comment: You need to check if the app has permission to access the contacts.

Comment: ohkay!! got it,.,need permissions.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople wrong on device - right on simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702903/abaddressbookcopyarrayofallpeople-wrong-on-device-right-on-simulator)