# Symbol not found: ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I've been working on an iPhone app which can brings the contacts from iPhone device to app , i've read about Addressbook privacy control , that is  ios6 need ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions , and which is working good in iOS6 but if i'm running this app in iOS5 and below i'm getting error like this :
**objective c Symbol not found: ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions** , please provide me the solution to run this app in iOS6 and below versions  ... thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner approach is to actually check for the symbol at runtime:

```
-(BOOL)isABAddressBookCreateWithOptionsAvailable {
    return &ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions != NULL;
}
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12533918/214350) for a full iOS 5/6 compatible approach to reading contacts from the address book.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use it in iOS5 because [the docs say](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions) `Available in iOS 6.0 and later`. In iOS 5 use the `ABAddressBookCreate` version (which is deprecated in iOS 6).