# Not able to access Contacts in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, addressbook

I am using the following code to get the contacts from the User's Phone

```
CFErrorRef  error;
__block BOOL accessGranted;
ABAddressBookRef myAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,&error);
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(myAddressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) 

{
if (!accessGranted && !granted)
{
alertViewDeny = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Deny Access" message:@"Deny" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
[alertViewDeny show];
[alertViewDeny release];
}
else
{
NSArray *allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(myAddressBook);


   DLog(@"allPeople %@",allPeople);
}
```

In Output I am getting  //Only for iOS7 and it is working iOS6.

allPeople( )

Comment: Why you are ignoring error completely in your code ? I bet this will give you an answer...

Comment: Also your code is not gonna work on iOS 5 and 4 - since there was a different way to get address book.

Comment: What in the world is `accessGranted`?  That's going to be garbage all the time since you never actually give it a value.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713193/ios-get-contact-phone-use-to-address-book