# ABAddressBookRef memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I am using the following code to initialize the address book in my application :-

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef;
self.addressBookRef=ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
```

However, the xcode analyzer is giving me the following message :-

```
call to function 'ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions' returns a Core Foundation Object with a +1 retain count
```

Now, as far as I have read, I can "remove" the above warning by the following 2 methods :-

- Release `addressBookRef` by using `CFRelease`
- Instead of `self.addressBookRef`, use `_addressBookRef` in second statement.

However, which one will be a better way and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All CoreFoundation API with `create` in their name return a CF object with a +1 retain count.  You then need to `release` the new CF object when finished with it. Example with your naming:

`CFRelease(self.addressBookRef);`

I strongly recommend reading this answer too:[iOS 6 Address Book not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12517394/558933)

Comment: right. But if we directly use _addressBookRef, why doesn't the xcode analyzer give a warning regarding its release ?

Comment: @Max: No idea why it doesn't give a warning - sorry.  Normally, if I'm using a CF object, I create it, use it and then release it rather than retain a reference to it.

Comment: what if in my method I need to return this addressBookRef? should I do myAddressBookRef = self.addressBookRef before CFRelease(self.addressBookRef) or what?

Comment: @xialinZZZ:I don't know what you mean - once you have the reference in a property you don't need to return it. If you have a problem you should ask a question.

Comment: after this comment I did post another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600766/whats-the-correct-way-of-releasing-an-object-when-it-also-needs-to-be-returned